# javascript error while passing parameter as combination of string and number

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm having trouble passing an argument to a javascript function.
Here is the code

```
function uncompress(src) {
var reg = /([a-zA-z])+/g;
var num = /[0-9]/;
var num_value = num.exec(src);
var str_value = src.match(reg);
var index = src.search(reg);
/*rest of the function body */
}
uncompress('3A12BC');
```

When i run the code. I'm getting a reference error: src is not defined. I know the problem is with the way I'm passing the argument but no idea how to correct it. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The code, as you posted it, does not produce the error you described.

I'm going to step out on a limb and assume that you did something like pass a number to the `uncompress` function.  In which case, something like this will work:

```
function uncompress(src) {

  if (typeof src === "number") {
    src = "" + src; // Convert to a string
  }

  if (typeof src !== "string") {
    throw "src must be a number of a string";
  }

  var reg = /([a-zA-z])+/g;
  var num = /[0-9]/;
  var num_value = num.exec(src);
  var str_value = src.match(reg);
  var index = src.search(reg);
  /*rest of the function body */
}
```

Comment: the one remaining line of the function is         'cut_string(str_value,index,num_value)' . And when I remove that the error is gone. Could you explain that plz?

Comment: You'll have to update your question (or open a new question) with an example that includes that code.  Not only do you not say what error you are getting, you aren't including the code and the call for `cut_string`.  The best way to get help at StackOverFlow is to post a small example of code that includes *everything* needed to recreate the problem.